# Magento 2 change knockout js template order

Tags: magento2, template, knockoutjs

How to change Magento 2 knockout js template order.
I want to change these blocks order for order summary table:
http://prntscr.com/ca9nbc

Moving orders items block above summary table.

Answer (score 2):

Solved with

```
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
```